# File drag/drop zone with button off to side (vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, label

I have a drag/drop file uploader, with a 'select a file' button to go with. So you can drop files in the 'zone' and also optionally click the 'select' button to get a file picker.
Thing is, I want the 'drop zone' to be empty and to the left of the button. How would I set that up? Here's what I have currently, but it sets the label/button right on top of the drop zone:

```html
<div id='drop-area' name='drop-area' style='z-index:10; left:3; position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 32px; height:32px; border: 1px solid #73AD21;'>
  <form class="my-form">
    <input type="file" id="fileElem" multiple accept="image/*" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)" style="display: none;">
    <label class="button" for="fileElem" style="float: right;">Select a File</label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the label out of the form, set position with 'left' or whatever, as needed.